# Do many classes slow down my Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, class, interface, typeclass

In my angular 7 application I created 200 to 300 of classes for model types ex: component.model.ts (only type checking purpose).

I am not creating any objects for those classes.

When I was navigating through the application my application gradually slowing down and facing performance issues.

I am suspecting these classes are the reason behind that, is my guess is right?

If I use interfaces instead concept of these classes for type checking, can I get any improvement in my application performance.

Answer (score 0):

For models I would use interfaces since they can't be initialized and will not appear in the final bundle. Interfaces are only there for you when you are developing. I think of interfaces as zero calories so yes I would use interfaces.

Now, are all those classes causing performance issues, I am not sure. I don't imagine creating 200 classes that should have been interfaces and were never instantiated causing issues.